# How to pass a ref to a method/function argument without unwrapping?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-composition-api

We're using the Vue Composition API and would like to pass a `ref` object, not just the value, as an argument to a function. Some code to clarify:

```js
import { defineComponent, ref } from '@vue/composition-api'

export default defineComponent({
  setup() {
    const driverId = ref()
    const truckId = ref()

    const clearDriverId = () => {
      driverId.value = null
    }
```

The code above works fine, but we need to duplicate the function `clearDriverId` for the `truckId` too. That's why we would like to create something like this:

```js
    const clearField = (field: Ref) => {
      field.value = null
    }
```

Accessed from the template:

```html
<q-input
  label="Driver ID"
  v-model="driverId"
>
  <template v-slot:append>
    <q-icon
      name="close"
      @click.stop="clearField(driverId)"
    />
  </template>
</q-input>
```

Of course, this does not work because the `ref` `driverId` gets unwrapped when passed from the template to the function. What is the correct way to pass a complete `ref` object to a function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution in `setup()` is to return an object/dictionary that contains all your `ref`s (preventing their auto-unwrap), which could then be used to pass a specific `ref` to your function. A utility (`toMyRefs()` below) that returns the `ref` along with a `ref` dictionary would be helpful in minimizing repetitive code:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <button @click="clearField(myRefs.driverId)">Clear driverId</button>
    <button @click="clearField(myRefs.truckId)">Clear truckId</button>
    <button @click="clearField(myRefs.carId)">Clear carId</button>
    <button @click="clearField(myRefs.trainId)">Clear trainId</button>

    <pre>
      driverId: {{ driverId }}
      truckId: {{ truckId }}
      carId: {{ carId }}
      trainId: {{ trainId }}
    </pre>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { defineComponent, ref } from '@vue/composition-api'

const toMyRefs = refs => ({
  ...refs,
  myRefs: {
    ...refs
  }
})

export default defineComponent({
  setup() {
    const driverId = ref(1)
    const truckId = ref(2)
    const carId = ref(3)
    const trainId = ref(4)

    const clearField = (field) => {
      field.value = 0
    }

    return {
      ...toMyRefs({
        driverId,
        truckId,
        carId,
        trainId,
      }),
      clearField,
    }
  }
})
</script>
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/pass-ref-to-function-in-template-tozlj?file=/src/components/Demo.vue)